# Inserção com PDO

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, pdo, inserir

Estou utilizando o [PHP](https://www.php.net/) com os objetos [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) e [PDOStatement](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.pdostatement.php), e meu código não retrata nenhum erro ou da warning, eu fiz a verificação das variáveis se estavam passando com `print_r` e está normalmente, porém não insere no banco.

```
<?php

require_once('conexao.php');

$nome = $_POST["nome"];
$sobrenome = $_POST["sobrenome"];
$cep = $_POST["cep"];
$estado = $_POST["estado"];
$cidade = $_POST["cidade"];
$telefone = $_POST["telefone"];
$modelo = $_POST["modelo"];
$marca = $_POST["marca"];
$fabricacao = $_POST["fabricacao"];
$foto = $_FILES['file'];

    $extensao = strtolower(substr($_FILES['file']['name'], -4));
    $novo_nome = md5(time()) . $extensao;
    $diretorio = "img/";
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $diretorio.$novo_nome);

$stm = new PDOStatement();

try {

    //Inicia a Transição
    $dbh->beginTransaction();

    /*Instrução SQL */
    $sql = "INSERT INTO estado(estado) VALUES (:estado)";

    /*Prepara o comando SQL */
    $stm = $dbh->prepare($sql);

    /*Pega os parâmetros e os avalia*/
    $stm->bindParam(":estado", $estado);

    /*Executa o comando SQL */
    $dbh->exec($sql);

    /*Pega o último ID colocado no banco de dados */
    $idEstado = $dbh->lastInsertId();

    $sql = "INSERT INTO cidade(cidade, Estado_idEstado) VALUES (:cidade, :Estado_idEstado)";
    $stm = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stm->bindParam(":cidade", $cidade);
    $stm->bindParam(":Estado_idEstado", $idEstado);
    $dbh->exec($sql);
    $idCidade = $dbh->lastInsertId();

    $sql = "INSERT INTO cep(:cep, Cidade_idCidade) VALUES (:cep, :Cidade_idCidade)";
    $stm = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stm->bindParam(":cep", $cep);
    $stm->bindParam(":Cidade_idCidade", $idCidade);
    $dbh->exec($sql);
    $idCep = $dbh->lastInsertId();

    $sql = "INSERT INTO veiculo(:modelo, :marca, :fabricacao, :foto, :descricao) VALUES(:modelo, :marca, :fabricacao, :foto, :descricao)";
    $stm = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stm->bindParam(":modelo", $modelo);
    $stm->bindParam(":marca", $marca);
    $stm->bindParam(":fabricacao", $fabricacao);
    $stm->bindParam(":foto", $novo_nome);
    $stm->bindParam(":descricao", $descricao);
    $dbh->exec($sql);
    $idVeiculo = $dbh->lastInsertId();

    $sql = "INSERT INTO usuario(:nome, :sobrenome, :telefone) VALUES(:nome, :sobrenome, :telefone, :Cep_idCep, :Veiculo_idVeiculo)";
    $stm = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stm->bindParam(":nome", $nome);
    $stm->bindParam(":sobrenome", $sobrenome);
    $stm->bindParam(":telefone", $telefone);
    $stm->bindParam(":Cep_idCep", $idCep);
    $stm->bindParam(":Veiculo_idVeiculo", $idVeiculo);
    $dbh->exec($sql);

    $dbh->commit();

} catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Houve algum erro na operação" . $e->getMessage();
    $dbh->rollBack();
}
?>
```

Está faltando alguma ação necessário para conclusão da inserção?

Comment: Quais são as mensagens de log no arquivo de log no servidor? O PDO está configurado para lançar exceções em casos de falhas?

Comment: Estou utilizando o XAMP como servidor (`localhost`) no caso, mas quando clico em `log` na parte em "`apache`", ele só me indica os erros de sintaxe mesmo (que havia cometido anteriormente), se eu colocar esse código, simplesmente não aparece nenhum erro no `log`. Mas quando instalei o XAMP só apenas habilitei a ext `PDO`

Comment: Na conexão via PDO você definiu o atributo `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` como sendo `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`?

Comment: Certo, defini corretamente, mas parece que é um erro de sintaxe de `SQL` no caso o `SGBD` seria o `MariaDB`: "You have an error in your `SQL syntax`; check the manual that corresponds to your `MariaDB` server version for the right syntax to use near ':estado)' at line 1"

Comment: `$dbh->exec($sql)` por que está executando a SQL diretamente ao invés da "versão preparada" dela, `$stm->execute()`?

Comment: Não sabia que o objeto `PDOStatement` tinha uma função `execute`, achava apenas que o outro objeto(no caso o `PDO`) tinha uma função dessa.

Comment: arquivo conexão é uma class?

Comment: Você está adicionando os dois pontos na frente do nome da coluna do banco (:). Coloque os dois pontos apenas no "values" como argumento para fazer o bindParams. Além disso, na sua última query você está adicionando mais dados do que os argumentos passados.